# mapping structures in struct C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

im trying to index number of struct under one struct.

im tying to pass the data in the first struct to the struct pointer but i get return null.

my code is :

```
struct complex{
char  * rNum;       /* real number */
char  *iNum;       /* imaginary number*/
};
 struct complex A = {"0","0"};
 struct complex B = {"0","0"};
 struct complex C = {"0","0"};
 struct complex D = {"0","0"};
 struct complex E = {"0","0"};
 struct complex F = {"0","0"};

struct mapping{
  char *key;
  struct complex *P;
 } complex_map [] = {
   { "A", &A },
   { "B", &B },
   { "C", &C },
   { "D", &D },
   { "E", &E },
   { "F", &F },
 };


 char call_complex(const char *name) {
  int i;

 for (i = 0; i < (sizeof(complex_map) / sizeof(complex_map[0])); i++) {
   if (!strcmp(complex_map[i].key, name) && complex_map[i].P->rNum) {
     complex_map[i].P->rNum;
     return 0;
   }
  }
  printf("Invalid\n");
 }
```

and my call function is :

```
void read_comp(char *str){
printf(" %s",call_complex(str));
}
```

when i run this code  i get return (null)

why?
thanks for helping

Comment: In the loop you `return 0;` ==> 0 is null

Comment: You need to return `complex_map[i].P->rNum;`, not put it on a line by itself. Also, the function should probably return `char *`, not `char`, which is why the compiler doesn't warn you about this.

Comment: This is just a typo on your part, so I am voting to close.

Comment: Also, for better testing, set different letters for the different structs `A`,`B`,..,`F`. Otherwise, you cannot test that the right one is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct complex{
char  * rNum;       /* real number */
char  *iNum;       /* imaginary number*/
};
 struct complex A = {"1","0"};
 struct complex B = {"2","0"};
 struct complex C = {"3","0"};
 struct complex D = {"4","0"};
 struct complex E = {"5","0"};
 struct complex F = {"6","0"};

struct mapping{
  char *key;
  struct complex *P;
 } complex_map [] = {
   { "A", &A },
   { "B", &B },
   { "C", &C },
   { "D", &D },
   { "E", &E },
   { "F", &F },
 };


char call_complex(const char *name) 
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < (sizeof(complex_map) / sizeof(complex_map[0])); i++)
    {
        if (!strcmp(complex_map[i].key, name) && complex_map[i].P->rNum) 
        {
            return *(complex_map[i].P->rNum); // Correction
        }
    }
    printf("Invalid\n");
}

int main()
{
    printf("Got: %c \n",call_complex("A")); // Just example
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.